# Twig: wrap variable in array if not already one, use empty array if missing

Tags: twig

I have a variable `modifier` passed to a few twig templates. I want to be able to not pass it at all, to pass a single string, or to pass an array of strings. I then want to be able to assume it is always an array of strings (possibly empty) in my template code.

At the moment I have at the start of the twig templates

```
{% set modifier = modifier | default([]) %}
{% if modifier is not iterable %}
    {% set modifier = [modifier] %}
{% endif %}
```

This does what I want, but is there an easier way? It's a lot of code to do something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could one-line it with a filter (can't seem to be able to mimic the default filter though)

```
<?php
    $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('wrap_array', function ($value) {
        return is_array($value) ? $value : [ $value, ];
    });

    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    $twig->addFilter($filter);
```

And use it in your template :

```
{% set foo = foo|default({})|wrap_array %}
```

Comment: You can test if `$value === null`, which is the case if the variable was undefined. I've done this and turned it into [an extension](https://gist.github.com/tremby/cdf7ef824291554b6a80). Now in twig I only need `{% for thing in someVar | wrapArray %} {{ thing }} {% endfor %}` and none of that preamble. But what I was really hoping for was a terse way to do this without an extension. As such, I'll leave the question open for a bit longer.